# AJAX calls and asynchronicity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm calling on two urls to get data and put on a table. Problem is, when there's only one ajax call everything is loaded in order it's supposed to. When there're two, all hell breaks loose.I started with promises but was told it wasn't a good idea [edit1] the way i was implementing it. suggestions please?

example of code:

```
 $.ajax({
"url":url1,
"crossDomain":true,
"dataType":"jsonp",
'success': function(response){ 
var datee = response.results.collection1[0].date;
var collection = response.results.collection2;
$(".table-group1").append('<tr><td class=well">'+ datee.substr(56,60) +'</td></tr>');
for (var i = 1; i < collection.length; i++){   
    $(".table-group1").append('<tr>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].domain.href + '</td>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].dns + '</td>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].mail + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].web + '</td>' +'</tr>');}},
error: function(err){
          alert('error!' + err);
      } 
});

 $.ajax({
    "url":url2,
    "crossDomain":true,
    "dataType":"jsonp",
    'success': function(response){ 
    var datee = response.results.collection1[0].date;
    var collection = response.results.collection2;
    $(".table-group1").append('<tr><td class=well">'+ datee.substr(56,60) +'</td></tr>');
    for (var i = 1; i < collection.length; i++){   
        $(".table-group1").append('<tr>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].domain.href + '</td>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].dns + '</td>' + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].mail + '<td class="well">' + collection[i].web + '</td>' +'</tr>');            
  }},
      error: function(err){
          alert('error!' + err);
      } 
});
```

Desired output is a table with two columns for each property (domain, dns, email web) from both url1 and url2.

html table:

```
<div class= "container_1">
```

```
<table class="table" border="1">
<th class="panel-heading"> </th>
<tr class="domain"> </tr>
<tr class="table-group1">
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: to be clear, you were not told Promises were not a good idea, you were told you were implementing Promises in a less than optimal way

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem than "all hell breaks loose"? I don't see why there should be any problem. The only issue is that it's unpredictable whether the rows from `url1` or `url2` will be added to the table first.

Comment: domain, dns, email, web is 4 columns, not 2, but who's counting?

Comment: I think he means 2 columns for domain, 2 for dns, etc ?

Comment: i meant two of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd handle the ajax side

```
var p1 = $.ajax({
    url: url1,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
var p2 = $.ajax({
    url: url2,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp"
});

Promise.all([p1,p2])
.then(function(results) {
    //results[0] is the the same as response in your code for url1
    //results[1] is the the same as response in your code for url2
});
```

As you now have all the data at hand, you should be able to format the output as you require

Comment: The `Promise.resolve` is definitely not needed here because `Promise.all` already does the very same thing implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sequence your two ajax calls so one finishes before the other is started, just do this;

```
$.ajax(...).then(function() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}).then(function(){
    // both are done here
});
```